# when i use command "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" it shows error like : key grid color:'"' does not look like a color org

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm

when i use command "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" it shows error like :
key grid color:'"' does not look like a color org

I am using matplotlib version 3.7.0
I also try to use this command "from matplotlib import pyplot as plt" and import matplotlib but still face same error. looking forward to positive response from you guys, thanks.

when i use command "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" in pycharm it shows error like :
key grid color:'"' does not look like a color org
I also try to use this command "from matplotlib import pyplot as plt" and import matplotlib but still face same error. looking forward to positive response from you guys, thanks.

Comment: Did you name any of your scripts as `matplotlib.py`?

Comment: no, my script name was else

Comment: "**any** of your scripts" - you cannot have anything named `matplotlib.py` in the folder (Using `else` is already a bad sign about how you're choosing filenames)